# Web project's folders/directories structure - Best practices

Tags: javascript, html, css, project-structure

I’m working on different web projects and I was wondering if there is any rule of thumb regarding the project/ folders structure?

Many of my apps are build in the structure where each file type has it’s own directory.
For example:

```
└─┬root
  |
  ├─┬node_modules
  | └ // node_modules (npm libraries)
  |
  └─┬www
    |
    ├─┬Libs // Js libraries 
    | |
    | ├─┬Angular
    | | └ … (.js files)
    | |
    | └─┬Bootstrap
    |   └ … (.js files)
    |
    ├─┬JavaScript // my Js files
    | |
    | ├─┬Services
    | | └ … // my services (.js files)
    | |
    | ├─┬Controllers
    | | └ … // my controllers (.js files)
    | |
    | ├─┬Directives
    | | └ … // my directives (.js files)
    | |
    | └app.js // js entry point
    |
    ├─┬StyleSheets
    | |
    | ├─┬Less
    | | └ … // my styles (.less files)
    | |
    | └─┬Css
    |   └ … // my styles (.css files)
    |
    ├─┬Views
    | |
    | ├─┬Pages
    | | └ … // pages layout (.html files)
    | |
    | └─┬DirectivesTemplates
    |   └ // templates layout (.html files)
    |
    ├─┬Assets
    | |
    | ├─┬Fonts
    | | └ … // app fonts (.ttf/ .woff files)
    | |
    | └─┬Images
    |   └ // app images (.jpg/ .png files)
    |
    ├─┬Data
    | |
    | └ // app info (.json files)
    |
    └index.html // web site entry point
```

However lately I see a few projects, where each module have it’s own folder with it’s code (.js file), view (.html file), style (.css/.less files) and data (.json file, images, fonts etc)
For example:

```
└─┬root
  |
  ├─┬node_modules
  | └ // node_modules (npm libraries)
  |
  └─┬www
    |
    ├─┬Libs // Js libraries 
    | |
    | ├─┬Angular
    | | └ … (.js files)
    | |
    | └─┬Bootstrap
    |   └ … (.js files)
    |
    ├─┬Modules
    | |
    | ├─┬moduleA
    | | |
    | | ├moduleA.js   //modules controller
    | | |
    | | ├moduleA.html //modules view
    | | |
    | | ├moduleA.less //modules style
    | | |
    | | └moduleA.json //modules data
    | |
    | ├─┬moduleB
    | | |
    | | ├moduleB.js  
    | | |
    | | ├moduleB.html
    | | |
    | | ├moduleB.less 
    | | |
    | | ├moduleB.json 
    | | |
    | | └moduleB-icon.png
    | |
    | └─┬moduleC
    |   |
    |   ├moduleC.js  
    |   |
    |   ├moduleC.html
    |   |
    |   ├moduleC.less 
    |   |
    |   ├moduleC.json
    |   |
    |   └moduleC-font.woff
    |
    └index.html // web site entry point
```

Are there any best practice regarding project structure?

Comment: The first structure looks like a single developer or a very small team. The second is for a larger project with more developers. Each module can be removed and replace, updated or changed without touching the rest.

Comment: In java, Maven is a de-facto standard. It does not allow a wide creativity in folder-structures. Are you using java?

Comment: I'm working mainly on client side apps, developed in javascript, with a large variety of frameworks like: angular, ember, jquery, ionic, webpack, grunt etc.. (on different projects)

Comment: use this page: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199004/best-practice-to-organize-javascript-library-css-folder-structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24199004/best-practice-to-organize-javascript-library-css-folder-structure)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your examples show two popular project structures, organize files by type or by module. I prefer the latter (code separated into modules) and I see it being used a lot for javascript frontend frameworks. It's something the [Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md) (a good reference for angular best practices) refers to as [folders by feature](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#folders-by-feature-structure).

I reference the Angular style guide because your examples showed Angular projects, but the concept can be translated to other frameworks. Code is organized by feature so it's easy the find the file you need to edit. As someone pointed out in a comment, this project structure scales well as the app and team grow in size.

Answer (score 0):

I have identified three type of design:

- [Atomic design](https://bradfrost.com/blog/post/atomic-web-design/) introduces a methodology for thinking of our UIs (components) as thoughtful hierarchies.
- [Folders-by-Feature Structure](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#folders-by-feature-structure): structure your app such that you can Locate your code quickly, Identify the code at a glance, keep the Flattest structure you can, and Try to stay DRY.
- The ["Rock-Hammer Structure example"](https://malarkey.github.io/Rock-Hammer/): structure your app using folders-by-type (**not recommanded** by the Angular style guide).

By the way, when using a framework, the style guidelines can provides great inputs to choose what is the most convenient for you. For example the [Vue.js style guidelines](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/?redirect=true#Priority-A-Rules-Essential-Error-Prevention) provide rules about components naming (which also determine files naming).